# Cloud Firestore Security Rules - only allow write to specific key in document

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm currently writing some rules for my app with a Firestore database. 
Currently everyone can read data and authenticated users can write.

```
  match /quizzes/{quizId} {
    allow read; 
    allow write: if request.auth != null;
  }
```

That works fine, but I also want unauthenticated users to write only to a specific key in a document.

Example content of a document:

```
{
  title: 'title',
  plays: 12,
  playedBy: [//Filled with user id's],
  ...
}
```

Is there any way that limits unauthenticated users to only have write access to the playedBy array and not the other keys of that document?

Answer (score 7):

Sure thing. But it may become a bit involved if you have a lot of fields.

Let's start with the simplest example. Something like this allows an unauthenticated user to write the `playedBy` as long as that is the only field in the document:

```
if request.auth != null || request.resource.data.keys().hasOnly(['playedBy'])
```

This works if the unauthenticated user is creating a new document, or updating an existing one. But it will stop as soon as the document contains more fields, since `request.resource.data` contains all fields the document will have after the write succeeds.

So the better alternative is to check that only the `playedBy` is modified, and that all other fields have the same value as before. The tricky bit there is handling the non-existence of fields, which I typically handle with a few helper functions:

```
function isUnmodified(key) {
  return request.resource.data[key] == resource.data[key]
}
function isNotExisting(key) {
  return !(key in request.resource.data) && (!exists(resource) || !(key in resource.data));
}
```

And then:

```
if request.auth != null &&
  request.resource.data.keys().hasOnly(['title', 'plays', 'playedBy']) &&
  isUnmodified('title') && 
  isUnmodified('plays')
```

The exact rule might be a bit off, but I hope this is enough to allow you to complete it yourself.

Comment: Thank you @Frank van Puffelen. I will give it a try!

Answer (score 6):

After the earlier answer (late 2019, I believe), Firebase has brought in [Map.diff](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Map#diff).

Something like:

```
match /quizzes/{quizId} {
    allow read; 
    allow write: if request.auth != null ||
      request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys() == ["playedBy"].toSet()
  }
```

Tested code where I use it can be seen [here](https://github.com/akauppi/GroundLevel-es6-firebase-web/blob/master/firestore.rules#L59-L61).

Comment: I'm unsure why this answer has been downvoted—this is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks, @akauppi.