# Firestore Security Rules: PERMISSION DENIED when Batching

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Consider this simple Firestore database structure:

**1: Firestore Structure**

```
cities/
    city1/
        name:Beijing
        likes: 0
        dislikes: 0
        ... more fields 
    city2/
        name: New York
        likes: 21
        dislikes: 1
        ... more fields
```

To protect the database from unintended operations, I added the following Firestore Security Rules

**2 Firestore Security Rules:**

```
// Allow read/write access to all users under any conditions
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {    
    match /cities/{cityId} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
      allow update: if request.auth.uid != null && 
request.resource.data.keys().hasOnly(["likes", "dislikes"]); 
    }
  }
}
```

Which basically allows me to enforce these requirements:

- Authenticated users can READ a city's data.
- Authenticated users can UPDATE the 'likes' and 'dislikes' fields of a city.

**Question**

How come, the above setup gives me a `Exception: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.`, when I try to use **batch writes**, but succeeds if I write changes individually?

E.g. below code (using **Batch** write) fails: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.

```
fun rate(likes: List<String>, dislikes: List<String>, done: (Boolean) -> Unit) {

    db.runBatch { batch ->
        likes.map { cityCollection.document(it) }.forEach { doc ->
            batch.update(doc,"likes", FieldValue.increment(1))
        }
        dislikes.map { cityCollection.document(it) }.forEach { doc ->
            batch.update(doc,"dislikes", FieldValue.increment(1))
        }
    }.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
        task.exception() // Exception: PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.
        done(task.isSuccessful) // false
    }
}
```

Whereas **without Batching**, the code works fine. e.g. this works perfectly:

```
override fun rate(likes: List<String>, dislikes: List<String>, done: (Boolean) -> Unit) {

    val tasks = likes.map { cityCollection.document(it) }.map { doc ->
        doc.update("likes", FieldValue.increment(1))
    }.union(dislikes.map { cityCollection.document(it) }.map { doc ->
        doc.update("dislikes", FieldValue.increment(1))
    })

    Tasks.whenAllComplete(tasks).addOnCompleteListener { task ->
        done(task.isSuccessful) // true
    }
}
```

Is there something special about batch writes/transactions that I need to know with respect to my security rules? I would like these updates to execute atomically, hence I tried to use batch writes initially. However, i cannot seem to get them working in combination with my security rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should know that `request.resource.data.keys()` contains **all** the keys in the existing document, not just the ones that are being updated.  `request.resource.data` represents the final state of the document if you allow the write to finish.  So, if you're updating a document that already contains other fields, your rule will always reject access, as `hasOnly` will return false.

Since you're not showing the contents of the existing documents in both cases, it's not really possible to say exactly where this is tripping up your code.  But this is almost certainly what's going on here.  It's irrelevant whether or not the update came from a single document write, a batch update, or a transaction.  They are all gated by the same rules.

(You used to be able to use a property called writeFields to find out only which fields were being updated, but that is deprecated - don't use it.)

If you want to perform per-field restrictions, it's actually much more involved than what you've written now.  You have to check if (and only if) a particular field has been modified, while also checking that no other fields have been changed.  See this question for more details:

[Cloud Firestore Security Rules - only allow write to specific key in document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56676255/cloud-firestore-security-rules-only-allow-write-to-specific-key-in-document)

Comment: Thanks! I was already considering moving the `likes` and `dislikes` into their own subcollection (which might still be easier).

Comment: Just spent a few hours scratching my head over this one. Kept getting a false positive simulating an 'update' against a non-existent UID; the test was obviously running against an empty `resource` so would always return ok if my request data matched any of the `hasOnly` fields. Is there a way to simulate already-present data?? IMHO there really needs to be a way to test against only the fields being updated, otherwise adding any arbitrary field via an admin interface (where security rules do not apply) will break the user interface unless the security rules are also updated.

Comment: There will be an easier way in the future, but today you have to check all the known fields.

Comment: How soon is now?

Comment: Strictly speaking, "now" is this very moment.  ;-)  But if you're asking when things might change, I don't know the future.  I just know it's been discussed.

Comment: Ok no worries. If it gives a sense of how convoluted a ruleset the current setup demands - I didn't realise there was a 1000x expression limit until I just hit it while attempting to secure (and strictly type) a fairly straightforward document made up of 19 fields of user-defined and trigger-appended data.

Answer (score 0):

Your document `request.resource.data` object can (and probably will) have more than just 'likes' and 'dislikes' which will cause rules to fail. The new canonical way to check what fields have changed is by diffing the document against the existing document (this replaces 'writeFields'). I've edited your rules to show this:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {    
    match /cities/{cityId} {
      function onlyLikedFieldUpdated() {
        return request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys().hasOnly(["likes", "dislikes"]);
      }
      allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
      allow update: if request.auth.uid != null && onlyLikedFieldUpdated();
    }
  }
}
```